# get the morgan combined format string

Tags: node.js, morgan

how can i return the morgan combined format string

```
async function sample(){
  const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/sample")
  const morganFormattedString = morgan('combined', {stream: {write: res => res }}) 
}
```

the **res** will be an object , i need to get the object of res to be converted as  below string which is done by the morgan internally

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jan/2019:04:59:10 +0000] "GET /sample HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/11.12.0"

Answer (score 1):

[`morgan`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan) returns *server-side* middleware which is supposed to be used for logging *incoming* requests. You're trying to use it *client-side* to log *outgoing* requests, which isn't its purpose. For what you're trying to accomplish [`axios-debug-log`](https://github.com/Gerhut/axios-debug-log) should work, but in order for it to log requests in the `combined` format, you'll have to [configure it yourself](https://github.com/Gerhut/axios-debug-log#configuration).

For reference, [this is how `morgan` currently defines the `combined` log format](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/314642713bc56bf83696de662ec88d842ff675bd/index.js#L152):

```js
morgan.format('combined', ':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ":referrer" ":user-agent"')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but if i save the code nodemon will restart the index.js and folders are created i am able to log the morgan logs in the proper format thats why i written a custom function to check since morgan returns a string format and winston returns that developer gives is an object format. check this question i have explained in detaill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250372/logger-implementation-using-winston-morgan-and-winston-daily-rotate-file The problem is the second one in the question,

Comment: You should mention the other question and the full description of the problem you're facing in this question as well.

Comment: can you check the other  question, so i can remove this question. I have posted everything in there

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax probably helps you:

```js
import morgan from "morgan";    
import express from "express";
const app = express();

app.use(morgan("combined"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello from the server end");
});
```